# Restart a command after it gets killed by the system

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash

I have been using [Gmvault](http://gmvault.org/) to backup my Gmail email accounts but since the machine I use for doing this job only has 1GB memory, it frequently got killed by the system (Ubuntu) when it exhausted all available memory. But if I restarted it, it would just resume from the point where it got killed.

So I would like to have a command that makes it restart after it got killed. I have tried this way but it didn't work:

```
for i in {1...999}; do gmvault sync peter123@gmail.com -d ./peter123 --resume; done;
```

When the system killed it, it killed the whole command (whole loop) rather than the current iteration in the loop.

Comment: Did you try with `trap`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [OOM Killer](http://linux-mm.org/OOM_Killer) [sends SIGKILL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7181152/96588), so [there's no way to gracefully handle the killing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1946902/96588). But you can simply [orphan the process](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessManagement#PIDs_and_parents) to avoid the surrounding loop being terminated:

```
while true
do
    nohup gmvault sync peter123@gmail.com -d ./peter123 --resume &
    pid=$!
    wait $pid || continue
    break
done
```

---

Test with a script that doesn't [run out of memory](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/24488/9570) on the third run:

```
$ cat test.sh 
if [ -e tries.txt ]
then
    tries=$(($(cat tries.txt) + 1))
else
    tries=0
fi
echo $tries > tries.txt

if [ $tries -lt 2 ]
then
    echo Failing $tries
    ulimit -v 50000
    :(){ : $@$@;};: :
fi
echo Succeeding
```

Output:

```
$ while true
> do
>     nohup bash test.sh &
>     pid=$!
>     wait $pid || continue
>     break
> done
[1] 28972
nohup: ignoring input and appending output to ‘nohup.out’
[1]+  Exit 2                  nohup bash test.sh
[1] 28973
nohup: ignoring input and appending output to ‘nohup.out’
[1]+  Exit 2                  nohup bash test.sh
[1] 28975
nohup: ignoring input and appending output to ‘nohup.out’
[1]+  Done                    nohup bash test.sh
$ cat nohup.out 
Failing 0
test.sh: xmalloc: cannot allocate 8388609 bytes (29577216 bytes allocated)
Failing 1
test.sh: xmalloc: cannot allocate 8388609 bytes (29577216 bytes allocated)
Succeeding
```

QED.